# ASP.NET with C# in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019, razor-pages

I want to develop a web application with ASP.NET and C# in Visual Studio 2019, but I found I have to use razor pages or MVC. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with either of those technologies, so can I develop without use them in Visual Studio 2019? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Check this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core?view=vs-2019

Comment: You forget to mention what you are familiar with? Please edit the question to include some context. If you are completely new to ASP.NET/C#, surely you need to study quite a lot of new things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. The UI for creating a new project looks a bit alien compared with 2017, but if you type "ASP.NET" in the search box, you get to choose the one you want:

[image]

Click that row and hit Next. You can then choose Empty in the next stage:

[image]

Finally you end up with the familiar ASP.NET C# project in Solution Explorer:

[image]